# driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "xpath") doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Newbie here, trying to learn and searched all over..
For some reason the 'click' option for the Xpath is not doing anything.
It opens the website, but from there doesn't do anything. Any idea?

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://google.com")
click = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/span/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/button[2]/div')
click.click()
```

It's supposed to open Google (which it does) and then click the 'Accept' button.

Love to know what I'm doing wrong here. I've tried both the xPath & Full xPath.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible that the element is not available or loaded. Use `ExpectedCondition as EC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the below refactored code with in-line explanation:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://google.com")
# Below line will create an object of WebDriverWait
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
# Below line will wait for 15s until Accept All button is in the clickable state and then clicks on it
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Accept all']"))).click()
```

**Note:**

- I removed the absolute XPATH which you used with a more reliable and user readable relative XPATH - `//div[text()='Accept all']`
- I have also implemented [Selenium' Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) to effectively wait and perform clicks

Comment: Glad it helped. Upvote and accept the answer which was useful and resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code to click on the button

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//some/xpath'))).click()
```

Comment: Legend, this solved my problem thankyou!!